# What is the proper way to integrate tree layout code into React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a website using React that shows a tree structure. (In terms of HTML it's not hierarchical at all, but just a bunch of divs at various positions, with SVG to draw connectors.)

To lay out the tree, I use an algorithm (Buchheim et al's improvement on Walker's algorithm) which looks at the widths of all the tree nodes and calculates the appropriate positions for each node.

I'm having trouble integrating this the "right" way. I cannot know the node's width until I'm inside its componentDidMount function, but at that time I don't know the position yet. So I need to change the position later, and modifying the DOM afterwards doesn't seem the React way. Making sure the tree component can access the nodes also feels slightly hackier than it perhaps needs to be.

Here's what I do now:

- The tree component's render function generates an array of node components.
- I've added some additional dictionaries directly to the tree component to store data I need. I found no way to use props or state for this. (I copied this from the Masonry mixin.)
- The node component's componentDidMount function calls a callback on the tree component to register its DOM node there. This feels pretty awful but it works.
- The tree component's componentDidMount function lays out the tree, sets the positions of the DOM nodes, and draws the connections between the nodes using SVG in a div that is not managed by React. That also feels a bit dirty but it's more because I needed to quickly get something that worked.

The main thing I dislike is having to sneak in parallel data structures to be able to change the positions of the DOM nodes after the nodes' componentDidMount function has been called.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I too had a React vs Tree problem too, slightly different from yours, and wrote up my journey here: http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2016-02-01-react-reconciliation.html Resizing sounds tricky, but the issue of when to mutate is the same I think. Hope it helps.